# Why are the ID's of youtube activities changing? How to identify an activity?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm syncing activities from a youtube channel to a local database. And to avoid double entries - I thought - I compare the activities ID.

I use this PHP lib: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client with the call

```
    $filter['channelId'] = 'MYCHANNELID';
    $filter['maxResults'] = 10; 
    $activitiesResponse = $youtube->activities->listActivities('id,contentDetails', $filter);
    $activities = $activitiesResponse->getItems();
```

The var_dump of $activities looks like this:

```
array(6) {
   [0]=>
    object(Google_Service_YouTube_Activity)#39 (9) {
       ["contentDetailsType":protected]=>
          string(45) "Google_Service_YouTube_ActivityContentDetails"
       ["contentDetailsDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
       ["etag"]=>
          string(57) ""gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/MpVG6ZegMNs7IzwG9kiCHZO7CGM""
       ["id"]=>
          string(36) "VTE0MDg2MzEyMTIxMzk4MjMwODcyMzI5MTI="
       ["kind"]=>
          string(16) "youtube#activity"
          .... and so on
```

But when reloading the activities stream THE SAME activity has ANOTHER ID and etag.

Perhaps I haven't understood the sense of an ID, but this is really weird and I'm looking for a solution to prevent double entries. (Without making a string compare on the text. ;o))

Comment: Or can perhaps somebody tell me what the #39 means and how to get this? This seems to last the same for all calls...